# Use Ubuntu Iptable to route public ip to pc in private network

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, router, iptables

I am currently set up a Ubuntu server as a Router which has two network interface.

- eth0 -> Connecting to public internet ( 10.10.1.78 )
- eth0:1 -> 10.10.1.79
- eth0:2 -> 10.10.1.83
- eth0:3 -> 10.10.1.81
- eth1 -> 192.168.10.1

And on the eth1, it connected to a switch, and the switch connected 2 computer. The corresponding ipaddress is :

- Instance1 -> 192.168.10.10
- Instance2 -> 192.168.10.11

The network mask is 255.255.255.0 and gateway all set to 192.168.10.1.

The ubuntu already setup dns server and dhcp server.
When i login to instance1 in the private, i already can access the internet and ping google.com.

For now, I need to do one thing. I want to Instance1 expose to outer network by public address 10.10.1.83.
Can I set some rule to redirect all incoming traffic from router with Destination url 10.10.1.83 to private network 192.168.10.10?

Many thanks!

---

**Edited**

Problem solved by setting rule in the iptable
with Destination NAT for protocol is TCP/UDP and destination is your public ip.
in Network address transaction setting.

Comment: Post an answer with your solution and get credit!